# What is serial upvoting reversed?

Tags: discussion

I know this [**user**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/18356/ram?tab=summary) have more than 1K rep, but today I checked his reputation, he got negative reputation and also it mentioned **Serial upvoting reversed**. What it means and for what reason he got negative rep?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the user got votes from the same person, or from a group of people, in a way that they were considered *serial voting*: votes given to posts not because their quality, but because the person who wrote them. To make an example, I could up-vote the questions asked from my girlfriend, but if I start voting almost of the questions she asks, and the number of votes is higher than a prefixed number of votes, then they would be reversed.

The reputation change is negative because the reputation obtained from serial up-voting is removed. If it were serial down-voting, the users would get back the reputation they lost, and in that case the reputation change would be positive.